# How can I use Lift asychronously with Nginx?

Tags: asynchronous, nginx, lift, netty

I want to use Nginx as a frontend redirecting requests to Lift application.

In this post 
http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Simple-deployment-of-Lift-apps-on-Jetty-Nginx-td1980295.html
David Polak recommends to use nginx as a reverse proxy. But in book "Nginx HTTP Server by Nedelcu C", I read this:"...the reverse proxy mechanism that we are going to describe
in this chapter is not the optimal solution. It should be employed in problematic
cases..." and FastCGI is described as the best choice.

Next option I see is to use Lift with Netty as here: https://github.com/jrwest/lift-and-netty-examples but it seems it just an expirement for now.

Maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a big fan of Nginx (make sure of that looking at my SO/SF profiles) and my opinion is that Nginx is a perfect fit for many-many uses.

Nginx can be used as a frontend to Lift application via HTTP transport (i.e. `proxy_pass` directive in Nginx), just like Nginx is used to proxy to Apache, Jetty, Tomcat or any other backend server talking HTTP. `fastcgi_pass` is designed to proxy to FastCGI backends. I did not see any benchmarks on which transport implementation is more effective, but I guess this difference will be smaller than differences implied by programming language/app server technologies.

One more note. I have no idea how FastCGI transport can be used to implement Comet applications. At the same time, Liftweb's Comet applications work perfectly via Nginx.